# Can I remove a single dimension of a boost::multi_array without copying its content?

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array

Below is my code for reshaping a boost::multi_array from shape `[3 4 2]` to `[12 2]`. Since the dimensions are fixed in a boost::multi_array, I'm first reshaping the three dimensional array to the shape `[12 2 1]` and then copy the first two dimensions into a new array.

Is there a simpler method which does not do any copying (I'd prefer just a view on the original data in the spirit of [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)).

Run with `g++ -g test.cc  && ./a.out`

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <cassert>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
main () {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  typedef array_type::index index;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  // indexer can be const a boost::array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  boost::array<array_type::index,3> idx = {{0,0,0}};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  // Assign values to the elements                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  int values = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        A[i][j][k] = values++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  std::cout << "array elements: " << A.num_elements() << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  std::cout << "array ndim: " << A.num_dimensions() << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  std::cout << "array size: " << A.size() << std::endl; // equivalent to a.shape()[0];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  std::cout << "array shape: " << A.shape()[0] <<" " << A.shape()[1] <<" " << A.shape()[2] << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  int verify = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        std::cout << "A[" <<i <<"]["<<j<<"]["<<k<<"] = " << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  boost::array<array_type::index,3> dims2 = {{12, 2, 1}};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  A.reshape(dims2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  std::cout << "array shape: " << A.shape()[0] <<" " << A.shape()[1] <<" " << A.shape()[2] << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  for(index i = 0; i != 12; ++i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    for(index j = 0; j != 2; ++j)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      for(index k = 0; k != 1; ++k) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        std::cout << "A[" <<i <<"]["<<j<<"]["<<k<<"] = " << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> Array2d;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Array2d B(boost::extents[12][2]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  for(index i = 0; i != 12; ++i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    for(index j = 0; j != 2; ++j){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      B[i][j] = A[i][j][0];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      std::cout << "B[" <<i <<"]["<<j<<"] = " << B[i][j] << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in the general case. What you can do is generating a *subview* with a lower dimensionality. I read your code that you want to have your 2D array as many elements as the original 3D array.

What you can do is to reuse the existing data of the 3D array with `const_multi_array_ref`:

```
boost::multi_array< int, 3 > a( boost::extents[ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ] );
boost::const_multi_array_ref< int, 2 > b( a.data(), boost::extents[ 2 ][ 12 ] );
```

Depending on the storage order this may do what your trying to aquire.

I would suggest to write a small wrapper around a `multi_array` which accesses the `multi_array` with the required index calculations.

Comment: thanks for this answer. This is definitely better than my solution. This modified line does what I want: `boost::const_multi_array_ref< double, 2 > B( A.data(), boost::extents[ 12 ][ 2 ] );`

Comment: If I understand correctly what `multi_array::reshape` does, the effect is similar to my approach (I would still consider writing a small wrapper for readability and flexibility). If my answer seems acceptable for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that this is possible by using a **View** (c.f. [Creating Views](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views)).

In my example:

```
... reshape ...

typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;                                                                       
array_type::index_gen indices;  
array_type::array_view<2>::type myview =       
    A[ indices[range(0,12)][range(0,2)][0] ];                                   
for(index i = 0; i != 12; ++i)      
  for(index j = 0; j != 2; ++j){  
    std::cout << "myview[" <<i <<"]["<<j<<"] = " << myview[i][j] << std::endl;
```